# Wrong internship dates in my CV for graduate application

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I am sorry if this is already repeated but it is a very urgent need of mine.
Actually in my CV for graduate applications, I put my industrial internship period as May to June 2016 and research internship period as May to June 2016. Actually it is may to June 2015 for industrial internship period. I didn't notice this mistake till now and I have already submitted my applications. What do I do?

Comment: Step 1: Don't panic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct the dates on your CV, then check the admissions website to see if there is any information about submitting corrections or amendments to your submitted application.  If there is not, email the corrected CV to the admissions office or department with a very brief line, along the lines of *"Hello, I submitted my CV with my applications but later noticed I put the wrong year on one of my internships.  I've corrected it in this version.  Thank you for your time."*   Include any relevant reference information to your application.

I honestly wouldn't expect it to get replied to, or possibly even noticed - admissions offices are very busy this time of year.  But this way if it does come up you can refer to your earlier email with the corrected version.

I also wouldn't fret about it over much.  It's remotely possible it could hurt you against an otherwise identically-qualified candidate who didn't make mistakes on their paperwork, assuming anyone even notices the discrepancy.  But even that seems like a very small detail against a good candidate.  The other thing I would suggest is that you proof read the whole thing carefully before you submit it with this correction; if you didn't proof read it well the first time and missed this mistake, it's possible you missed others too.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Also, my concern is that it would come across as carelessness on my behalf and hurt my process? The majority of the universities I am applying are Ivy League, so some advised me against emailing and letting this detail pass since the competition is cut throat.

Comment: That would assume no one notices the error, which I think is a questionable assumption.  Assembling a time line of your activities seems like a reasonable bit of analysis, and the overlap would be clear then.  Mistakes happen in academia; showing you can find and fix them seems like a better signal than making them and having someone else find it later.  But if you feel uneasy about bringing it to their attention I really don't think it's such a harmful error that you couldn't let it slide and offer a revision if asked.

Comment: While making the error implies carelessness, **apologizing and admitting to an error implies sincerity and integrity**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should find out how to submit the corrections and then submit them. That's precisely what I would do because it's important to avoid the appearance of lying. The overlapping dates could make you  appear to be a "superstar" when, in reality, you might only be a "shining star". :>)